# Meteor collection inaccessible ("is not defined")

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I am trying to gain visibility of a collection called cronHistory (part of https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron which appears to be functioning fine).

In the meteor shell (server side), I can see the collection exists in amongst the others e.g. my `events` collection:

```
> Meteor.Collection.getAll()

[{ name: 'events',
    instance:
     { _makeNewID: [Function],
       _transform: null,
       _connection: [Object],
       _collection: [Object],
       _name: 'events',
       _driver: [Object],
       _restricted: true,
       _insecure: undefined,
       _validators: [Object],
       _prefix: '/events/',
       before: [Object],
       _hookAspects: [Object],
       after: [Object],
       hookOptions: [Object],
       direct: [Object],
       _c2: [Object] },
    options: undefined },
```

...

```
 { name: 'cronHistory',
    instance:
     { _makeNewID: [Function],
       _transform: null,
       _connection: [Object],
       _collection: [Object],
       _name: 'cronHistory',
       _driver: [Object],
       _restricted: false,
       _insecure: undefined,
       _validators: [Object],
       _prefix: '/cronHistory/',
       before: [Object],
       _hookAspects: [Object],
       after: [Object],
       hookOptions: [Object],
       direct: [Object] },
    options: undefined } ]
```

But I can't access it from the shell (or elsewhere):

```
> cronHistory.findOne()
ReferenceError: cronHistory is not defined
    at [object Object]:1:-61
    at Script.(anonymous function) [as runInThisContext] (vm.js:41:22)
    at /Users/technical/code/mssc/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/shell-server.js:305:27
    at /Users/technical/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1vct6fi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:33:40
```

Which is not true of other collections:

```
> FutureNotifications.findOne()
{ _id: 'btX6XGnXtaCkaEBzB' }
> Events.findOne()
{ _id: 'r3sw6kw9M8fPXGmvd',
  name: 'rstierstnrstrst',
  location: 'rein',
```

How can I access it? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is probably how you declare and import collections. You can help us help you if instead of a GitHub link, you create a small set of code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where would you host such example code? I was hoping it would be clear to someone from the code snippets I have posted why this collection is inaccessible. I am not declaring this collection, it is made by the syncedCron package, and then viewable with `Collection.getAll()`. Strikes me as strange that it can this Collections array but not be directly accessible to e.g. the shell. How can that be?

Comment: `Meteor.Collection` has no official way to get a collection by name. You should dig into package internals, see my detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Packages are stored in the global `Package` array. You can access package internals in Meteor shell using `Package["percolate:synced-cron"]`.

After digging a minute in the [source code](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron/blob/master/synced-cron-server.js), this is probably what you want:

```
Package["percolate:synced-cron"].SyncedCron._collection.findOne();
```

Please note that you can access `Package` in the browser console just as well, it stores client-side packages then. Obviosly, you should only this for debugging purposes.